# Did the biblical apostle James visit Ireland?

Tags: ancient-history, christianity, ireland

I remember reading in a magazine that the biblical apostle [James the Greater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James,_son_of_Zebedee) visited Ireland 400 years before Saint Patrick.

- Is it true that he went on a mission to Northern Ireland? Forgive me if I overlooked something but if I google anything about the apostle James in Ireland a bunch of Saint Patrick day crap pops up.
- Is there a book someone could point me to that tells about this? (optional)

Comment: Are you sure that the "biblical apostle James" really existed, first of all? What is the evidence of that, except the Gospel? On my opinion, this question does not qualify as a question on history.

Comment: @Alex : that would verge on conspiracy theories. No serious historian denies the existence of the apostles and the fact that they traveled to many places of the Mediterranean during the fundation of the early Christian churches.

Comment: @vsz: But if the only source about them is the New Testament, how can one possibly answer any question on the detail of their travels, if they are not mentioned in the NT?

Comment: @Alex: Do you honestly think that serious historians accept this based only on the Bible? You keep asserting that only the New Testament asserts that James existed, without bothering to actually check that out, which is kind of interesting given the fact that you're demanding evidence yourself. No, there is actual historical evidence! Of course, whether we should consider that evidence reliable is another matter.

Comment: @Alex Evidence.....I don't know, the fact that many people---including unbelievers--- gave accounts of him and the other apostles. That is like saying Jesus didn't exist when many pagan Romans admitted his existence.

Comment: There were apostles, and they did things and had names. Whether the names we have today are connected to the "correct" actions is a very open question. Much of the NT is faked in the sense that the writers used others' names to give themselves credibility. While that doesn't make what they wrote untrue, it makes it very hard to know what can be relied on. As for @DustinJackson's point: I know of no surviving pagan Roman source that claims first-hand knowledge of Jesus; just re-tellings of what they'd heard from others.

Comment: There is a very similar legend that apostle Andrew visited Kiev and and introduced Christianity in Rus. Seems evident that it was invented at some time after the actual introduction of Christianity there. But generally one cannot prove or disprove this sort of legends.

Comment: @Nagora While not supporting my argument, [this article](http://www.gotquestions.org/did-Jesus-exist.html) provides some interesting reading material on the subject.

Comment: @Alex As Lightness said, no serious historian could say that Jesus or the Apostles never existed. That is like saying Abraham Lincoln was never President of the United States, or JFK was never assassinated.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan: Sure. Neither a serious historian will say that "they existed". Because the precise meaning of this is unclear. There is a HUGE difference between Jesus and Lincoln, don't you feel it ?

Comment: "Biblical Apostle James" is a literature personage, like Dom Quixot. Because all we know about him is taken from ONE book. Did Dom Quixot visit Ireland? This is not a history question. If you believe that THAT book tells you literal truth, it is OK, but again this has nothing to do with history.

Comment: @Alex I never said that 'THAT book' tells the literal truth. I am saying that over a billion people profess to be Christians and a **nonexistent person** could not impact society to such a degree. It is obvious that there were apostles and there was a Jesus, even if they were not who they said they were or even had different birth names. I am content to believe that a **real man** that we now know as Jesus had a severe case of schizophrenia.

Comment: It is perfectly historical to ask what James the apostle, or Jesus, did during his lifetime. It is also perfectly historical to question whether he existed at all. History has been profoundly impacted by (possibly) non-existent people, like Romulus, John Dee (cargo cult), Heracles, Lao Tse... some of these people may have existed, and some not. From a historical point of view, you could argue it doesn't even matter. –  Ne Mo 6 hours ago

Comment: No, there is absolutely no reason to believe that James ever visited Ireland, or even knew that it existed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no credible evidence that the apostle James ever visited Ireland. According to [Acts 12:1-22](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nrs/acts/passage/?q=acts+12:1-2), James was beheaded in Jerusalem by Herod Agrippa, with no indication that he had traveled. Acts does include passages about other apostles' travels--most notably Paul, but also [Philip in Samaria](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nrs/acts/passage/?q=acts+8:4-8) and [Peter in Caesarea](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nrs/acts/10.html).

The fourth century church historian Eusebius mentions the early Christians' travels in spreading the gospel to [Palestine and Antioch](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf201.iii.vii.iv.html), [Rome](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf201.iii.vii.xv.html), and [Egypt](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf201.iii.vii.xvii.html). Within the same chapter Eusebius mentions [James' death in Jerusalem](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf201.iii.vii.x.html) without suggesting that James had traveled.

Much later, a legend arose that James had gone to Spain to preach the gospel before returning to Jerusalem to be martyred. And even later--in the 17th century--[Spanish chronicler Joseph Pellicer wrote](http://omniumsanctorumhiberniae.blogspot.com/2014/07/saint-james-apostle-spain-and-ireland.html) that James had also spent time in Ireland.

Answer (score 6):

Since England had not been invaded by the Romans at this time, and Ireland was beyond that, the odds are extremely unlikely that any such event took place.  There are always legends created in far-flung areas of having Biblical 'celebrities' visit, but travel was not easy in those days.

Most evidence says that the James apostles were martyred in the Holy Land.

Comment: As I thought. Further research has yielded similar answers.

Comment: According to Wikipedia Britain was invaded first times even before Jesus' birth: "In the course of his Gallic Wars, Julius Caesar invaded Britain twice: in 55 and 54 BC". See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar%27s_invasions_of_Britain

Comment: Those were two quick raids, and would in fact make it even **less** likely that a traveller from Rome could move through Britain onward towards Ireland.

Comment: The Romans never invaded England. England did not exist.

Comment: Wiki has 44 AD for James' death and Claudius successfully invaded Britain in 43 AD. Julius Caesar's excursions a century before were not a proper invasion.

Comment: Romans managed to install a king, Mandubracius, who was friendly to Rome during the 54 BC invasion. Still the actual point here is that there was awareness of Britain already before Jesus birth. Also it would not have been necessary for Rome to actually invade Britain before James' trip anyway.

Comment: @NeilKirk: There's a quite obviously implied "what we now call" in there.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any evidence that the Biblical Apostle James-(a.k.a. "James The Greater") ever visited Ireland. Such a claim tends to echo the lore behind Joseph of Aramathea-(sp?) visiting Glastonbury, England 2000 years ago-(i.e. The story of the Holy Grail, which is more Monty Python than historical reality).  Irish Christianity really originated with Saint Patrick during the 400's AD/CE-(about 350-400 years after Saint James' "martyrdom").

James, very likely visited Spain where he began his proselytizing/missionary work-(though, for the record, there is no verifiable primary historical evidence which proves this).  He was reported to have spent much of his time in Northern Spain, though when returning to Jerusalem, he was the 1st Apostle to have been executed/"martyred" in 44 AD/CE. The mixed historical and legendary story was that James' head was buried/encased in Jerusalem-(If my memory is correct, there is either an Armenian or Syrian Church that claims to have the martyred/encased head of Saint James). However, his body was reported to have been transported from Jerusalem, to the Galician coast of Northwest Spain. When Spanish Catholic Monks or Priests discovered the (alleged) body of Saint James 1200 years ago, the Camino Del Santiago/Road of Saint James was born. About 1000 years ago, a Shrine Cathedral was built in the Saint's honor and it is the final destination point for trekkers who walk along the Camino over the past 1000 years-(Saint Francis of Assisi, was one of the earliest historical figures to have walked the Camino Del Santiago).  It should be noted that Saint James/"Santiago", is the Patron Saint of Spain and is second only to Saint Peter in terms of Sainthood.

(It should also be noted that James' brother, was John, as in Apocalypse John or Saint John, the Author of the Book of Revelation who spent his later years on Patmos Island in the Aegean and is buried in Ephesus in Western Asia Minor/present-day Turkey).

The story of James, like many early Christian Saints and "Martyrs", is a complex mixture of history and legend. It is often difficult to distinguish the historical reality from the lore-(or to try to distinguish...the indistinguishable). Nevertheless, the mixed history and legend of Saint James has played a central role in certain Christian cultures over the centuries...most notably Spain, though not in Ireland-(to the best of my knowledge).

(Side note:  There is an above written statement which says, "The Romans never invaded England.  England did not exist."  That is both correct and incorrect. It is certainly true that the name, "England", did not exist during the time of the Roman invasion, which dates back to Julius Caesar.  But, it is certainly true that the land of Britannia/Britain was invaded by the Romans over 2000 years ago.  The name, "England", means, "Land of the Angles". The Angles, were the 1st (or one of the earliest) Germanic tribes who invaded Roman occupied Britannia. However, the majority population living under Roman and early Anglo-Saxon Britannia, were Celts).